# Huge difference between api response and application web transactions time?

Tags: networking, connection, newrelic

My frontend app connects to an api server to get its data, the frontend app web transactions time is as in the figure below.

[image: Frontend app web transactions response time]

Although my api response time is nearly ~100ms, the frontend app web transaction response time is nearly ~600ms.

[image: Api response time]

**So what could be the reason of the ~400ms difference?**